# Defining conditional value at risk as loss function in Tensorflow/Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensor, loss-function

I am trying to define a custom loss function in Tensorflow/Keras: average of errors that are higher than a specified quantile. When fitting the model it gives me 'loss: nan', and I'm not sure why.

So far I wrote this code:

```
def expected_shortfall_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    alpha = 0.05  # Significance level for expected shortfall calculation

    # Calculate the error
    error = y_pred - y_true

    # Sort the errors in ascending order
    sorted_errors = tf.sort(error)

    # Calculate CVaR
    es = K.mean(sorted_errors[int(n_obs*(1.0-alpha)):])
    return es
```

How should this be modified to properly return the conditional average of losses higher than 95% quantile in this example?

Comment: Your loss is not differentiable